# How abstraction is achieved using interfaces in java

Tags: java, oop, abstraction

I know

> Abstraction is process of hiding the implementation details and
>   showing only the functionality.

But by using interfaces we can not implement any thing.We need the implemented class also 
to develop applications.For example in java we have List interface which has sub classes like LinkedList and ArrayList.They provided the code for those classes also.We are able to see the code for those implemented code.Can any one give me an example for abstraction.

If i only give the interface to someone, then i can achieve the abstraction.But any example for this?

Comment: `List interface which has sub classes like LinkedList and ArrayList`. That's  utter wrong statement.

Comment: *ability* to see the code is not the same as a *requirement* to see the code. The point of the interface is that you shouldn't *need* to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding here means making the client of your code *independent* of the underlying implementation.

Interfaces specify *what* you can do. Implementations specify *how* to do it.

As *How* tos improve/change with time, the client (another piece of code) using interfaces continues to work without modification. The client still gets what it wants, but probably in a more efficient manner now.

Abstraction is a style of programming aimed at easing the lives of programmers and consumers. It has nothing to do with hiding the *source code* from others. There are probably other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a method

```
public void m(List<String> strings) {
```

You *don't* know the concrete type implementation of `strings`, only the `interface` - which also means, that your other methods `a` and `b` could call `m` using either a `LinkedList` or a `ArrayList` and you don't need two methods, one for each concrete implementation type.

Comment: by seeing this one i don't know.Any how i have implemented class with me.So i can see the source code

Comment: Yes, you could, but you should rely on the interface you're getting and not on the concrete type. For example you could do `instanceof` tests in the method casting `strings` to concrete types, but if you only use characteristics of `List`, just use it.

Comment: Here what we are hiding exactly?

Comment: Check the implementation details of various `List` implementations what you are hiding - the best thing: You couldn't care less what details are hidden, because you rely on the `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

`Abstraction` relates mostly not to some class itself, but to **relation of it with its clients**. Let's for example class `LinkedList` implements interface `IList` (I'm more familiar with .NET) and provides it as it's **public API**.

When client uses `LinkedList` via `IList` interface, client doesn't know how it is implemented.

So, reducing and hiding of information is all about abstraction principle. More generally, abstraction provides level of loose coupling between producer and consumer of some functions.

For example, if some client knows about implementation details of some interface (or class), thus it can make some assumtions about it's behavior and internal implementation, which need to be avoided. Otherwise you cannot easy switch or change implementation of IList in this case. This generally leads to the idea of agilty, loose coupling, etc and SOLID is all about it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, it just means that (using the example you provided) you **must** have **all** the methods implemented in the interface to make a functional class. 
This fact make you responsible for providing the means to implement these methods, the contact (interface) is only interested that you implement them.

So,

> functionality

is to know that there is a method `add(E e)` in all concrete subclasses of 'List`(you know that there is this method and you can uses it to add elements to the`List`) and

> hiding the implementation details

means you don't know how (and usually don't care) it is implelented.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
If you make interface Airplanes,and classes Warplanes, Civilplanes, Woodenplanes all implement that interface, you can as a argument in some method let's call it - public void Fly(Airplanes airplane){some code..} use all classes you previously made but you have to implement(make a body to) all methods from Airplane interface in all classes that implement that interface or you can use them as a return type also in case that method is :

```
public Airplanes Fly(Airplanes airplane){
   some code..
   boolean c1=(airplane instanceof Civilplanes);
   boolean c2=(airplane instanceof Woodenplanes);


   if(c1) return new CivilPlanes();
      else if(c2) return new Woodenplanes();
          else return new Warplanes(); }
```